# Sklearn: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I want to use Sklearn to vectorize my data in a big csv file, I used the following code:

First TRY:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='file', stop_words = 'english', ngram_range=(1,2))

vectorizer.fit_transform('test.csv')
```

But I got this error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Second TRY, but error was still raised:

```
import csv

file = open('test.csv', 'r')

f = file.readline()

vectorizer.fit_transform(f)
```

Third TRY: This one did work, but it was killed due to out of memory.

```
file = open('test.csv', 'r')
a = file.read()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english', ngram_range=(1,2))
de = vectorizer.fit_transform(a.split('\n'))
```

How to use fit_transform in Sklearn to process a large CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

You consider your input as a `file` and you give it a `string` in both cases (`file.readline()` returns the first line of your file as a `string`).

Instead, give it a file.

Do as follows:

```
file = open('test.csv', 'r')
vectorizer.fit_transform(file)
```

Comment: Slightly easier solution might be to just edit `input='file'` -> `input='files'`, then the object expects a list of file names rather than a file object.

Comment: Yes but he only has one file and the vectorizer does not expect to get a list of strings but a list of files (`file.readlines()` returns a list of strings)